# Wiki Syntax to Create Child Page From Current Page

Tags: wiki, syntax

This *seems* like it should be a very simple task/question.

We are currently on SharePoint 2007.

I am in the process of editing a particular department's Wiki page, so imagine the breadcrumb to the page as follows:

```
Home > Departments > IT > Groups > HR
```

Now, let's say I am currently editing the page for HR. On that page, I'd like to create a link to a new page, which contains HR's various bits of Contact Information. One would assume I would use the syntax:

```
[[ContactInfo]]
```

and after clicking the link, which would then take me to the brand new page to edit, I would see my breadcrumb as:

```
Home > Departments > IT > Groups > HR > ContactInfo
```

...right? Because after all, I am trying to create a "Contact Info" page for HR, **not for everyone**.

The actual result: (you guessed it)

```
Home > Departments > IT > Groups > ContactInfo
```

*Not what I want.*

How do I create a link to a new page that is going to be a child page of the one I'm editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that there is no such thing as "child page". If you need to create a hierarchy, then HR has to be a container. Within this container you would have the default page and then other pages. Just like what SharePoint does with sites.

If for some reason all your pages need to be in the same container, then you cannot expect SharePoint to understand your own logic. In this case you would need to build your own navigation - breadcrumb or other.

Comment: SharePoint wikis are only wikis in the sense you can create pages automagically with the double bracket syntax.  There is *nothing* else wikilike about them when compared to things like Mediawiki.